# open cart tax issue

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I'm new to Opencart. In fact I'm working in my first project that is in Opencart 2.3.0.2. It's almost done.

Now the client need the price of a product should be inclusive of tax.

now actually it's working like the tax is added with unit price. I need it to be included.

ex: Rs.100 (includes GST 18%)

```
incorrect:
Unit Price: 100
GST@18%: 18
Total: 118

Correct:
Unit Price: 84.75
GST@18%: 15.25
Total: Rs.100
```

instead of 100*18/100, we need to calculate 100*100/118
(100*100/118)-100 to get GST

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin->System->Settings, edit your Store, and select the Option tab.  There is a setting called "Display Prices With Tax."